# Nested resources and setting up my controllers, rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

So Im trying to nest my resources so that members have images, here is my route

```
resources :members, :except => [:new, :create] do
    resources :tattoos
end
```

which gives me these paths when I rake routes:

```
       member_tattoos GET    /members/:member_id/tattoos(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tattoos"}
                      POST   /members/:member_id/tattoos(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"tattoos"}
    new_member_tattoo GET    /members/:member_id/tattoos/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"tattoos"}
   edit_member_tattoo GET    /members/:member_id/tattoos/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"tattoos"}
        member_tattoo GET    /members/:member_id/tattoos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tattoos"}
                      PUT    /members/:member_id/tattoos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"tattoos"}
                      DELETE /members/:member_id/tattoos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"tattoos"}
              members GET    /members(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"members"}
          edit_member GET    /members/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"members"}
               member GET    /members/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"members"}
                      PUT    /members/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"members"}
                      DELETE /members/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"members"}
```

But if I use these link_to's

```
<%= link_to "Manage tattoos", member_tattoos_path %>
<br />
<%#= link_to "Upload new tattoo", new_member_tattoo_path %>
```

I get an error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"tattoos"}
```

Even tho the tattoos_controller.rb does exist. What gives?

And do I need to set up my tattoo_controller in any specific way? I ask because now that I have the links right, I cant submit any new records, Im getting an error:

```
Started POST "/members/1/tattoos/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-17 13:11:40 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/members/1/tattoos/new"):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `:member_id` in when using your path helper like so:

```
member_tattoos_path(:member_id => @member.id)
```